# Fill range with string only if cell is empty and another sibling cell is not empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have a table, with columns `start` and `finish`
and I'd like fill cells in `finish` column automatically with `0` only if `finish` cell is empty and `start` cell next to it not empty

So far I have this script that supposed to fire when a cell in `start` column (`A3:A` range) selected:

```
function onSelectionChange(e)
{
  const range = e.range,
        sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
        col = range.getColumn(),
        row = range.getRow(),
        columns = [1], //check only first column (A)
        startRow = 3; //range A3:A
//only allow single cell selection starting at A3:A
  if (row < startRow || !columns.includes(col) || range.getNumColumns() !== 1 || range.getNumRows() !== 1 || sheet.getName() !== "Sheet1")
    return;

  for(let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)
  {
    const start = sheet.getRange(startRow, columns[i], 10, 1), //get 10 rows
          finish = sheet.getRange(startRow, columns[i] + 1, 10, 1); //get 10 rows

      if (!start.isBlank())
      {
        if (finish.isBlank())
          finish.setValue(0);

      }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this fills **EVERY** cell in `finish` column and only when **ANY** cell in `start` column not empty and **EVERY** cell in `finish` column is empty

Do I have to loop through each cell individually to achieve this?

Comment: how you want to update the cells? when you edit or something, or you want to update the cells in one go?

Comment: My original thought was to update entire column at once, since it might already contain some data. But doing it on a single row would work too, which would work with `getRange(row, columns[i], 1, 1)`

Comment: Can you provide a sanitized copy of the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

For updating the single row one by one.

Try below sample script:-

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const row = range.getRow();
  const column = range.getColumn(); 
  if(column === 1)
  {
    const finsh_Column =  range.offset(0,1);
    if(finsh_Column.getValue().length === 0)
    {
      finsh_Column.setValue(0)  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason use `getValue().length` instead of `isBlank()`?

Comment: No, you can use isBlank too, if you're getting true on `if`.. i just prefer using length, which i know not a great approach..

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind to process all the rows at once it could be something like this:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 3) add_zeros();
}

function add_zeros() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A3:B' + sheet.getLastRow());
  var data = range.getValues();

  data.forEach(row => row[1] = (row[0] != '' && row[1] == '') ? 0 : row[1]);

  range.setValues(data);
}
```